# Latex table not show in page

Tags: tables, sectioning, page

I write the script for show table in section like this.

```
\section{RESULTS AND DISCUSSION}
This paragraph will end the body of this sample document.
Remember that you might still have Acknowledgments or
Appendices; brief samples of these
follow.  There is still the Bibliography to deal with; and
we will make a disclaimer about that here: with the exception
of the reference to the \LaTeX\ book, the citations in
this paper are to articles which have nothing to
do with the present subject and are used as
examples only.
%\end{document}  % This is where a 'short' article might terminate


\begin{table*}
\small
\centering
\caption{Some Typical Commands}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|} \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell[cc]{Product \\ ID}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3}\\ \cline{2-10}
 & A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)} & A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}& A & \makecell[cc]{Specify\\ Size} & \makecell[cc]{Error\\(\%)}\\ \hline
1 & \makecell[cc]{Method \\new} & 6&11.70 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & No & 3.24 & \makecell{Method+\\Data} & 6 & 10.55\\ \hline
2&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
3&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
4&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
5&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
6&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
7&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
8&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
9&B& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
10&A& 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{Conclusions}
This paragraph will end the body of this sample document.
Remember that you might still have Acknowledgments or
Appendices; brief samples of these
follow.  There is still the Bibliography to deal with; and
we will make a disclaimer about that here: with the exception
of the reference to the \LaTeX\ book, the citations in
this paper are to articles which have nothing to
do with the present subject and are used as
examples only.
%\end{document}  % This is where a 'short' article might terminate

\section{References}
Generated by bibtex from your ~.bib file.  Run latex,
then bibtex, then latex twice (to resolve references)
to create the ~.bbl file.  Insert that ~.bbl file into
the .tex source file and comment out
the command \texttt{{\char'134}thebibliography}.
% This next section command marks the start of
% Appendix B, and does not continue the present hierarchy

\end{document}
```

when I run the script the table show on the middle of the last page. The table should show before reference section. How to show table in section{RESULTS}.

The table should move to this position.
[image]

Comment: Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... You can omit floating environment `table*` for example.

Comment: Maybe [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144)  could be interesting.

Comment: `table*` is a special float for  two-column documents that should be placed in a previous page  ... but ..  Hey? Is a two-column document ? Are there previous pages? and ... and .... and why not show us  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can fully understand the problem?

Comment: Because the document ended before the table* was used, it went into a page of floats (like using [p]), hence the centering.